# iPhone 5 power button rattles on vibrate

Tags: hardware, iphone

My iPhone 5 has a slightly "loose" power button. Not like its going to fall off or anything, but it visibly wiggles a little bit, and if I stand the phone up and then quickly turn it upside down, or bump it, I can hear and see it move.

As this is my first iPhone, is this normal?

Just to clarify, it's not mushy, it just seems like the plastic "outer button" wiggles around on top of the actual button sensor inside. It certainly has a nice firm click when pressed.

Edit: certain vibrate patterns also make it rattle very fast, making a buzzing sound. If I put my finger lightly on it, it stops.

Edit 2: macrumors is full of people with similar beefs. I'm guessing this isn't just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds normal, if a bit looser than my 4S. If it concerns you, you might be able to get a replacement unit from an Apple Store, though there are no guarantees that it will have better buttons (when I replaced my iPhone 4 two years back for a different issue, the replacement I received had noticeably mushier buttons).

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not mushy, it just seems like the plastic "outer button" wiggles around on top of the actual button sensor inside. It certainly has a nice firm click when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two takes to this issue - first is you have a one year hardware warranty and if it somehow falls off, you have coverage as long as it doesn't get a huge dent in the same spot making it look like you broke it. Second is to compare yours to other devices around (in a store - with friends). If yours is clearly not the same as the rest, I would presume Apple would repair it at your convenience through AppleCare. You can call, get help online or visit a store for that. They also will be able to help you determine if yours is truly normal or out of the ordinary.